# Windows Forms RichTextBox strange behaviour

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, rtf

My logging system generates rtf-formatted strings and puts them directly to a RichTextBox:

```cs
RichTextBox1.rtf = MyRTFFormattedString;
```

Each line in log usually contains some text and links:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1251\fs16

  {\colortbl;\red255\green0\blue0;\red0\green255\blue0;\red0\green0\blue255;\red0\green0\blue0;\red100\green100\blue100;\red255\green255\blue0;}

 {\cf5 [11:02:59] }Схема {\cf3{\field{\*\fldinst HYPERLINK "BCA-02-3202-THAP-2.01-0"}{\fldrslt  BCA-02-3202-THAP-2.01-0}}} успешно экспортирована в файл {\cf3{\field{\*\fldinst HYPERLINK "H:\\tmp\\PID\\Draft\\pdf\\THAP\\3202\\01112013-!-3202-THAP-!-0-0.pdf"}{\fldrslt  H:\\tmp\\PID\\Draft\\pdf\\THAP\\3202\\01112013-!-3202-THAP-!-0-0.pdf}}}\par
  {\cf5 [11:03:00] }Схема {\cf3{\field{\*\fldinst HYPERLINK "BCA-02-3202-THAP-2.02-0"}{\fldrslt  BCA-02-3202-THAP-2.02-0}}} успешно экспортирована в файл {\cf3{\field{\*\fldinst HYPERLINK "H:\\tmp\\PID\\Draft\\pdf\\THAP\\3202\\01112013-!-3202-THAP-!-0-0.pdf"}{\fldrslt  H:\\tmp\\PID\\Draft\\pdf\\THAP\\3202\\01112013-!-3202-THAP-!-0-0.pdf}}}\par
  {\cf5 [11:03:02] }Схема {\cf3{\field{\*\fldinst HYPERLINK "BCA-02-3202-THAP-2.03-0"}{\fldrslt  BCA-02-3202-THAP-2.03-0}}} успешно экспортирована в файл {\cf3{\field{\*\fldinst HYPERLINK "H:\\tmp\\PID\\Draft\\pdf\\THAP\\3202\\01112013-!-3202-THAP-!-0-0.pdf"}{\fldrslt  H:\\tmp\\PID\\Draft\\pdf\\THAP\\3202\\01112013-!-3202-THAP-!-0-0.pdf}}}\par
  {\cf5 [11:03:03] }Схема {\cf3{\field{\*\fldinst HYPERLINK "BCA-02-3202-THAP-2.04-0"}{\fldrslt  BCA-02-3202-THAP-2.04-0}}} успешно экспортирована в файл {\cf3{\field{\*\fldinst HYPERLINK "H:\\tmp\\PID\\Draft\\pdf\\THAP\\3202\\01112013-!-3202-THAP-!-0-0.pdf"}{\fldrslt  H:\\tmp\\PID\\Draft\\pdf\\THAP\\3202\\01112013-!-3202-THAP-!-0-0.pdf}}}\par
  \par
  \par
  \par
  \par
  {\cf5 ОТЧЕТ ОБ ЭКСПОРТЕ}\par
  {\cf5 ===============================================================}\par
  {\cf3 Процесс успешно завершен}\par
  \par
  Экспортировано: 4 схем из 4 за 00:00:07.60\par
}
```

After I put this string to RichTextBox everything looks pretty good:
[image: RichTextBox Content]

The issue is no `LinkClicked` events generate by cliking links in last 2-3  lines in log. Count of such "dead" lines depends on total lines count in log (for ex. 4 lines - 1 dead. 10 lines - 3 dead etc).

All lines have the same rtf syntax.
All links in all lines are working properly when document is opened in WordPad.
Moving last line to the first position in log makes links in that line work properly.

How to solve this problem?
Maybe there are some limits on hyperlinks count in RichTextBox?

Answer (score 0):

Try using RichTextBox v5:

```
public class RichText50W : RichTextBox
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams prams = base.CreateParams;
            if (LoadLibrary("msftedit.dll") != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                prams.ClassName = "RICHEDIT50W";
            }
            return prams;
        }
    }
}
```